# Access 2007: Duplicating search form criteria to secondary query?

Tags: forms, vba, search, duplicates

I have an example search form query that I'd like to duplicate the output from in order to control an additional side query. I have two goals with this:

1) Send data to a report that matches the search results.
2) Be able to limit the columns that are being output to Excel - ie. exclude the search textboxes from the spreadsheet output (ie. hoping for detail section-only output).

To give a little bit more detail - this is going to be a read-only database and I'm trying to set this up to run in the background for the users so that they can have clean Excel exports and print exactly what they wish.

My code for the form search query looks like this:

```
Dim strWhere As String
Dim lngLen As Long
Const conJetDate = "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"

If Not IsNull(Me.txtQ_ID) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Q_ID] = " & Me.txtQ_ID & ") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.txtAnswer) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Answer] Like """ & Me.txtAnswer & """) AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.txtItem) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Item_Condition] Like """ & Me.txtItem & """) AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.txtComments) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Comments] Like """ & Me.txtComments & """) AND "
End If

lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen <= 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please enter search criteria.", vbInformation, "Nothing to do."
Else

    strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)
    Me.Filter = strWhere
    Me.FilterOn = True
End If
```

Is there a clean way to get this to feed back into SQL? I've seen this possibility suggested in another thread but there wasn't enough detail to go on.

Thank you in advance!

Matt B

Comment: As a side note - I had four such queries to work with and I was able to at least straighten one of them out. It only consists of one text field so I duplicated the same query the form was built on and put this in as the search criteria for the relevant line:                                                                   like "*" forms![form_name]![textbox] "*". That seems to work out okay as a fill-in with one text field, just that I'm not so sure how finicky this could get if I'm trying to keep the capability for the users to insert asterisks as wildcards in their searches.

Comment: ^^ Please note there were supposed to be asterisks in those quotes, something in the site formatting removed them.